# Run Mono (linux) From Pen

Tags: linux, mono, usb

Is it possible to run mono, for linux, from a usb pen, with absolutly no installation on the target machine??

edit:
The reason I'm asking this, is because I have been developing an app in WPF and WCF targeted for windows, but last week a new customer came and has a POS with linux system, and if it that is wasn't enough it has a flash disk with only (around) 200mb... and the .NET libs will take almost all that, not counting my app. So I need a USB/MONO solution...

Comment: I wouldn't recommending doing it but i can see reasons you MIGHT want to and it can apply to cd. +1 -edit- guys, just bc you dont like the question it doesnt mean its off topic.I need to package portable software -all- the time (but in windows so i dont need to worry about .NET installation)

Comment: Another thing to note is the lack of WPF support within the mono platform, check out: http://www.mono-project.com/WPF

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, assuming that you compile Mono yourself, and specify a prefix (like `/opt/mono`).  Then you will have to ensure that you mount the flash drive in such a way that `/opt/mono` refers to the directory on the flash drive containing this prefix.

If you do not have root access on the target machine but are able to mount the volume anyway, then in your compilation environment you will have to configure with a prefix contained in a directory that you have write access to on the target.  For example, if you are user "foo" on the target machine, then you could use a prefix `/home/foo/opt/mono`.  Then, after mounting the flash drive, symlink `/home/foo/opt/mono` to the corresponding directory on the flash drive.

Comment: You may also be able to make use of some of the environment variables  to overcome the issues with knowing the mount path ahead of time. http://mono-project.com/Parallel_Mono_Environments